# Performance effects of moving mysql db to another Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, networking, amazon-ec2

We have an EC2 running both apache and mysql at the moment. I am wondering if moving the mysql to another EC2 instance will increase or decrease the performance of the site. I am more worried about the network speed issues between the two instances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EC2 instances in the same availability zone are connected via a 10,000 Mbps network - that's faster than a good solid state drive on a SATA-3 interface (6Gb/s)

You won't see any performance drop by moving a database to another server, in fact you'll probably see a performance increase because of having separate memory and cpu cores for the two servers.

If your worry is network latency then forget about it - not a problem on AWS in the same availability zone.

Another consideration is that you're probably storing your website & db file on an EBS mounted volume.  That EBS block is stored off-instance so you're actually storing a storage array on the same super-fast 10Gbps network.

So what I'm saying is... with EBS your website and database are already talking across the network to get their data, putting them on seperate instances won't really change anything in that respect - besides giving more resources to both servers.  More resources means more data stored locally in memory and more performance.

Comment: Great answer. MySQL loves RAM. Ideally, all indexes should be loaded into memory at all times.

Comment: Fantastic answer! Clears all my doubts. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends largely on what resources apache and MySQL are using.  They can happily co-habit if demands on your website are low, and each are configured with enough memory that they don't shell out to virtual memory.  In this instance, they are best kept together.

As traffic grows, or your application grows, you will benefit from splitting them out because they can then both run inside dedicated memory.  Provided that the instances are in the same region then you should see fast performance between them.  I have even run a web application in Europe with the DB in USA and performance wasn't noticeably bad! I wouldn't recommend that though!

Because AWS is easy and cheap, your best bet is to set it up and benchmark it!